# How would I make a boolean made up of the circled shapes work properly on a small, flat, coin-shaped cylinder

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

[image]

What I'm trying to do it 3D print a small coin like thing and make a slight indent in the shape of the 6 triangles and 4 circled circles into the coin shape. I tried it earlier and it did not work and was terrible, and there's definitely a way to do it I'm just not too advanced at modeling, so help would be appreciated. I can provide more info if needed. (Also not sure how to create the triangle shapes well, I did it but they were bad and interacted horribly with the base cylinder.)

Comment: add subdivide the surface and try boolean modifier or upload the blend file and I'll do it for you

Comment: Boolean should work, be sure that your triangles and circles are not coplanar (on the same plane) with the base mesh. In other words, make sure they stick out from the base mesh a bit. And try using curves to make the triangles.